# How to process ODATA Function Import not returning a wrapper element

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

In our solution we are calling a custom CDS-based ODATA API on S/4HANA side which includes a function import. For this we generated the Java service for the ODATA interface via the maven-plugin. The called function import is based on BOPF and the generated implementation does not return a result matching the expectation of the SAP Cloud SDK, which is that the resulting JSON object has a member with the name of the function import.

We checked if we could change the generated ODATA implementation, but found no configuration for doing so in S/4HANA.

I have debugged the SDK implementation when making the call and found the following code in the FunctionImportResponseParser, which makes this assumption:

```
    <T> T getEntityFromResponse(
        final InputStream responseContent,
        final String edmFunctionImportName,
        final Class<? extends T> entityJavaType )
        throws IOException,
            IllegalArgumentException
    {
        final JsonObject responseJsonObject = getJsonObjectFromResponse(responseContent);

(X)     if( responseJsonObject.has(edmFunctionImportName) ) {
            final JsonElement jsonElement = responseJsonObject.get(edmFunctionImportName);
            return getEntityFromJsonElement(jsonElement, entityJavaType);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Due to the if-statement marked by (X) and the fact that the function import directly returns the object not wrapping it in the expected member, the result null is returned.

So the queston for me is, if it should be possible by the SDK to also handle this case, or whether the error lies somehow in the S/4HANA API not returning an ODATA conforming result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to customize this behavior when consuming the API. As you already noticed the current implementation expects the JSON result to contain an object with the same key name as the *function import* name being called in the OData request.

Here is a temporary workaround to your issue:

- Override the *FluentHelperFunction* implementation class with the following "getFunctionName" method:

  ```java
  @Override
  @Nonnull
  protected String getFunctionName()
  {
      final String callingMethod = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
      if( "generatePath".equals(callingMethod) ) {
          return "TheFunctionNameInUrlPath";
      }
      if( "executeSingle".equals(callingMethod) ) {
          return "TheKeyOfODataResponse";
      }
      throw new IllegalStateException("This should not happen.");
  }
  ```

While this is not great code, we will check how this can be made easier in the future with SAP Cloud SDK.

---

**Update:** Unfortunately the JSON response, that you are receiving, is not wrapping the contents into another object inside of root element "d". This makes the problem much more difficult to workaround.

If you still want to use the *SAP Cloud SDK* in this scenario, you would need to adapt some of the internal code. Instead of the `getFunctionName` listing above, please try the following change of the `execute` (or `executeSingle`) method:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.json.JsonSanitizer;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataExceptionType;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataGsonBuilder;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.result.GsonResultElementFactory;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.result.ResultElement;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

...

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public T execute( @Nonnull final ErpConfigContext configContext )
        throws ODataException
    {
        final HttpEntity httpEntity = accessibleQuery(configContext);

        final ProposalHeader response;
        try( final InputStream content = httpEntity.getContent() ) {

            final String rawContent = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            final JsonElement responseJsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(JsonSanitizer.sanitize(rawContent));

            // select JSON root object
            final JsonElement jsonElement = responseJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("d");

            // deserialize contents
            final GsonResultElementFactory elementFactory = new GsonResultElementFactory(ODataGsonBuilder.newGsonBuilder());
            final ResultElement resultElement = elementFactory.create(jsonElement);
            response = resultElement.getAsObject().as(getEntityClass());
        }
        catch( final IOException | IllegalArgumentException | JsonSyntaxException e ) {
            throw new ODataException(ODataExceptionType.ODATA_OPERATION_EXECUTION_FAILED, "Failed to read OData result.", e);
        }
        return response;
    }

    private HttpEntity accessibleQuery( @Nonnull final ErpConfigContext configContext ) {
        try {
            final Method query = FluentHelperFunction.class.getDeclaredMethod("query", ErpConfigContext.class);
            query.setAccessible(true);
            Object httpEntityRaw = query.invoke(this, configContext);
            return HttpEntity.class.cast(httpEntityRaw);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | ClassCastException e) {
            // log error
            // throw exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

You can change the generic type `T` to your expected response class. Also change the lines `// log error` and `// throw exception` to match your application use case, such that error handling can be easily done in the future. Additionally you should introduce some `null` checks to this code.

Comment: I am afraid this won't work. Like I said, there is no wrapping element for the return type. So there is no reasonable "TheKeyOfODataResponse" to map the complete JSON object, since the getJsonObjectFromResponse() call before already removes the single wrapper which is "d" in the JSON respone.

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully the change of `execute` method helps in your case.

Comment: That should work, so I would accept this. However, it would be great, if the response parser would natively support this, as an alternative path in case the returned JSON does not have a member with the respective function name.